# How can I add a hand-painted texture as an input to a shader node?

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I am using a noise texture to generate the mask for the land/water layers of a planet

[image]

I want to bias this noise texture with something hand-painted so I can roughly shape the continents by hand but use the noise to break up the edges automagically.

I think I want something like this

[image]

except instead of a fixed "Value" node, I want the value to be taken from some monochrome texture. Then I want to paint onto that texture in Blender and see the effect on the coastline immediately.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Have you tried the image texture node?

Comment: As LOLock said, an Image Texture Node fed into the Factor of the Mix node bringing in the Blue there. I'm not so sure that the Value input you have there Adding to the Noise will serve as a stencil, but you can try that. Main thing is to make sure you reference UV for mapping so that the paint lines up. Simple black rgb image painted white will work.